# A query on kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have created a k8s cluster on GCP. And then I installed kubectl tool  and Google Cloud SDK locally. Other than that I have done no extra configuration. I just added kubectl location to system path.

Now when I do 'kubetcl get pods', it fetches me the list of pods deployed in GCP cluster.

But how does kubectl know about that cluster? I surely didn't provide any information to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubectl uses a [Kubeconfig file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) which has a `server` attribute with the IP or hostname of the Kubernetes API server hosted in GCP.

By default, kubectl looks for a file named config in the $HOME/.kube directory. You can specify other kubeconfig files by setting the KUBECONFIG environment variable or by setting the --kubeconfig flag.

From the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl) gcloud command automatically updates the kubeconfig file with correct API Server address and other parameters.

Comment: It seems when I connected via Google cloud SDK shell, kubeconfig is updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use kubectl to interact with the cluster, then you need to update cluster details in kube config. The config file is probably have a file named config in the $HOME/.kube directory.

Please refer [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#explore-the-home-kube-directory)